# Signal created with matlab function block in simulink

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure, simulink

I want to generate an arbitrary linear signal from matlab function block in simulink. I have to use this block because then, I want to control when i generate the signal by a sequence in Stateflow. I try to put the out of function as a structure with a value field and another time as the following code:

```
`function y = sig (u) 

if u == 1 
t = ([0 10 20 30 40 50 60]); 
T = [(20 20 40 40 60 60 0]); 


S.time = [t ']; 
 S.signals (1) values ​​= [T '].; 
S.signals (1) = 1 dimensions.; 

else 
N = ([0 0 0 0 0 0 0]); 
S.signals (1) values ​​= [N '].; 
end 
y = S.signals (1). values 
end `
```

the idea is that u == 1 generates the signal, u == 0 generates a zero output.

I also try to put the output as an array of two columns (one time and another function value) with the following code:

```
function y = sig (u) 

if u == 1 
S = ([0, 0]); 
cant = input ('Number of points'); 
for n = Drange (1: cant) 
S (n, 1) = input ('time'); 
S (n, 2) = input ('temperature');  
end 
y = [S] 
else 
y = [0] 
end 
end
```

In both cases I can not generate the signal.

In the first case I get errors like:

This structure does not have a field 'signals'; new fields can not be added When structure has-been read or used

or

Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of 'tempstrcutsf2/MATLAB Function / u' is a one dimensional vector with 1 elements.

or

Undefined function or variable 'y'. The first assignment to a local variable Determines its class.

And in the second case:

Try and catch are not supported for code generation,

Errors occurred During parsing of MATLAB function 'MATLAB Function' (# 23)

Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of 'tempstrcutsf2/MATLAB Function / u' is a one dimensional vector with 1 elements.

I'll be very grateful for any contribution.

PD: sorry for my English xD

Comment: Your code looks poorly formatted, at least contains several syntax errors. Please review it.

Comment: Why not use a Signal Builder block or From Workspace block, inside an Enabled Subsystem?

Answer (score 0):

You have many mistakes in your code 
you have to read more about [arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html) and [structs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) in matlab

1. here `S = ([0, 0]);` you're declare an array with only two elements so the size will be static
2. There is no function called `Drange` in mtlab except if it's yours

See this example with strcuts and how they are created for you function

```
function y = sig(u)
    if u == 1 
        %%getting fields size
        cant = input ('Number of points\r\n'); 

        %%create a structure of two fields 
        S = struct('time',zeros(1,cant),'temperature',zeros(1,cant));

        for n =1:cant 
           S.time(n) = input (strcat([strcat(['time' num2str(n)]) '= '])); 
            S.temperature(n) = input (strcat([strcat(['temperature'...
                num2str(n)]) '= ']));  
        end 
            %%assign output as cell of struct 
            y = {S} ;
        else 
            y = 0 ;
    end 
end
```

to get result form y just use

```
s = y{1};
s.time;
s.temperature;
```

to convert result into 2d array

```
2dArray = [y{1}.time;y{1}.temperature];
```

Work with arrays

```
function y = sig(u)
    if u == 1 
        cant = input ('Number of points\r\n');
        S = [];
        for n =1:cant
            S(1,n) = input (strcat([strcat(['time' num2str(n)]) '= ']));
            S(2,n) = input (strcat([strcat(['temperature'...
                num2str(n)]) '= ']));
        end
        y = S;
    else 
         y = 0 ;
    end 
end
```

Comment: First of all thank you for answer my question so soon.

Comment: First of all thanks for answer my question so soon. But I still don't understand some things. My output is "y". but you put "s=y{1}". my question is: Is not enough to put y={S} in order to generate the signal hat I want?
Do yo test the code? because i couldn't make it works, i think i have problems in the ports and data manager configuration.

Comment: I really didn't get your point what specifically do you mean, So if you want to work directly with arrays see modified answer